# Access Apache Server only via public keey

Tags: apache, security

is it possible to restrict public access to an apache web server in a way similar a ssh-server can restrict access via public keys?

**Setting:**
I've got a micro server with apache and a web-application. This application needs to be accessed only by less than 10 users. I want to exclude all others, esp. bots, hackers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea: Use ssh tunnelling and firewall the webserver so it only accepts local addresses.